# How to get a value in a dictionary inside a list in python and further index a value from it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I had challenge problem that I got to solve, this is what the data looks like,

```
data = [{'Clay':[x for x in range(2, 3)]}, 
        {'George':[x for x in range(7)]}, 
        {'Buddy':[x for x in range(5, 8)]}, 
        {'Mark':[x for x in range(7, 11)]}, 
        {'John':[x for x in range(1, 10)]}]
```

The Challenge Question was to find a value in data say "Buddy" and further index a number/value from it  say 6, this is what I came up with so far but I got stuck here-

```py
data = [{'Clay':[x for x in range(2, 3)]}, 
        {'George':[x for x in range(7)]}, 
        {'Buddy':[x for x in range(5, 8)]}, 
        {'Mark':[x for x in range(7, 11)]}, 
        {'John':[x for x in range(1, 10)]}]

def find_usr(usr, val):
    if usr in data:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

find_usr(usr="Buddy", val=6)
```

It returns `False` I'm not sure what is going wrong here I did a few searches on a topic but coudn't find a possible solution.
Any further debugging details are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you asked correctly, I hope this block of code may help:

```
def find_usr(usr, val):
    for dictionary in data:
        # Checking each dictionary in the list
        if usr in dictionary.keys():
            # Only if the user in the current dictionary
            if val in dictionary[usr]:
                # If the value in the list of the user
                return True
            # If the value is not in the list of the user
            break  # We can stop the loop becuase we have found the user
    return False
```

By the way, if you are using a list of dictionaries that have only one key and one value, it will be better to use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
data = {'Clay':[x for x in range(2, 3)], 
        'George':[x for x in range(7)], 
        'Buddy':[x for x in range(5, 8)], 
        'Mark':[x for x in range(7, 11)], 
        'John':[x for x in range(1, 10)]}
```

So the code will be more efficient:

```
def find_usr(usr, val):
    if usr in data.keys():
        # Only if the user in the current dictionary
        if val in data[usr]:
            # If the value in the list of the user
            return True
        # If the value is not in the list of the user
        break  # We can stop the loop becuase we have found the user
    return False
```

Comment: This also works fine @Sparrow thanks for the post!